# rsync : did not see server greeting

Tags: cwrsync

We are trying to build CRAN reposiotry locally in windows using cwrsync.  we are using rsync command to download all the packages etc.  Since the machine where we are running is behind proxy we are also using RSYNC_PROXY variable.  when we execute rsync command we are getting "rsync : did not see server greeting".  Can you please help us.

rsync -av --chmod u+rwx -e "ssh -i d:\r-download" "/cygdrive/d/r-download"
rsync -rtlzv --delete cran.r-project.org::CRAN "/cygdrive/d/download"

Not sure whether its because of -e ssh.

Regards...Srini

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
with daemon you cannot use '-e' ('--rsh') option.

From man page:

> CONNECTING TO AN RSYNC DAEMON
>
> ```
>    It is also possible to use rsync without a remote shell as the
>    transport.  In this case you will directly connect to a remote rsync
>    daemon, typically using TCP port 873.  (This obviously requires the
>    daemon to be running on the remote system, so refer to the STARTING AN
>    RSYNC DAEMON TO ACCEPT CONNECTIONS section below for information on
>    that.)
>
>    Using rsync in this way is the same as using it with a remote shell
>    except that:
>
>    o      you either use a double colon :: instead of a single colon to
>           separate the hostname from the path, or you use an rsync:// URL.
>
>    o      the first word of the "path" is actually a module name.
>
>    o      the remote daemon may print a message of the day when you
>           connect.
>
>    o      if you specify no path name on the remote daemon then the list
>           of accessible paths on the daemon will be shown.
>
>    o      if you specify no local destination then a listing of the
>           specified files on the remote daemon is provided.
>
>    o      you must not specify the --rsh (-e) option.
> ```

Check last line.

Regards.